# How to make gradle generate a valid pom.xml file at the root of a project for maven users?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, compatibility

While only for two days now, I am definitely sold on using gradle for all of my Java projects, and drop pom.xml from the root of all my projects.

However, I would like to remain maven-compatible, in the sense that I would like for a gradle task to be able to generate a suitable pom.xml at the root of the project should the user want it.

At this moment, the only reference to a pom.xml I have is in this section of the build.gradle file (this is, with very few modifications, what is found [here](http://jedicoder.blogspot.fr/2011/11/automated-gradle-project-deployment-to.html)):

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            beforeDeployment {
                MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment);
            }

            repository(url: sonatypeRepoURI) {
                authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername,
                    password: sonatypePassword);
            }

            pom.project {
                name "${name}";
                packaging "bundle";
                description "${description}";
                url "${projectURL}";

                scm {
                    url "${gitroscm}";
                    connection "${gitroscm}";
                    developerConnection "${gitrwscm}";
                }

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name "Lesser General Public License, version 3 or greater";
                        url "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html";
                        distribution "repo";
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        id "whocares";
                        name "whocares";
                        email "whocares";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I extract the `pom.project` out of this very deeply nested construct into a task which could generate a pom.xml (by default, the generated pom.xml is in `build/poms/pom-default.xml` and looks quite good)?

More importantly, is it possible to extract that `pom.project` out of `uploadArchives` while still being able to refer to it?

Full link to the build.gradle file: [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-core/raw/master/build.gradle).

Comment: Did you look at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#N1511A , I haven't used it, but it looks like what you're describing.

Comment: @KirilRaychev this looks interesting, but integrating it into the existing execution flow is where I am at a loss :/

Comment: If you want to build the pom manually, just run the `writeNewPom` task. If you want to generate a pom on each build, add `build.dependsOn writeNewPom` to your `build.grade`

Comment: Uh, I already have the maven plugin loaded... And `gradle writeNewPom` fails saying it cannot find the task!

Comment: Work's fine for me - look at this example `build.gradle` - https://gist.github.com/jmruc/5852692

Comment: Does not work for me! Honestly I am really lost here :/

Comment: @KirilRaychev OK, this was a mistake on my part; can you please post your comments as an answer, with the original link and all? I'll upvote it (previous failures were my fault entirely); now, your sample file generates the pom.xml in `build/`, not at the root... This change and I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: works fine but does not contain any dependencies. How to create pom with dependencies

Comment: @deadpool007 maven manages them automatically; the dependency engines in maven and gradle are pretty similar in that regard. What case did you encounter where dependencies were missing?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the [gradle maven plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html). This adds the  `pom` convention method to your project, which you can use in a task to generate a `pom.xml` file, like

```
task writeNewPom {
    doLast {
        pom {
            project {
                groupId 'org.example'
                artifactId 'test'
                version '1.0.0'
                inceptionYear '2008'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                        distribution 'repo'
                    }
                }
            }
        }.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
}
```

Then you call `gradle createPom` to generate the pom.xml in the project root. Of all the things in the pom definition, you should really provide `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`, other thins like `licenses` are not that important.

You can also look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/jmruc/5852692) for a project definition with some dependencies, and try running it to see what it produces.

Some of the new keywords were added and some techniques were deprecated. [Please check](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html)

Comment: I got pom file with no dependency :(

Comment: How i can get dependency on pom.xml?

Comment: How can I add a properties section?

Comment: There is one issue with doing it this way: It will overwrite pom.xml even if the contents are already correct. This makes all later build stages run even when they don't need to, since it changes the file timestamp. (I don't know of a better option either)

Comment: NB: produced an empty POM for a multi-project build.

Comment: `<<` has been deprecated and finally removed in Gradle Version 5.x, so above snippet with raise an exception with recent versions of Gradle. You need to use `Task.doLast()` instead, see also  
 [could-not-find-method-leftshift-for-arguments...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793095/could-not-find-method-leftshift-for-arguments-after-updating-studio-3-4)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories { 
mavenLocal() 
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'

    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.5.RELEASE'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"

    testCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
}
test {
  testLogging {
    // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
    events 'started', 'passed'
  }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.12' }
task createPom  {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'sg.test.spring.web.guide'
            artifactId 'sg-web-initial'
            version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

You can name the task `createPom` to `anyTaskName` as you like.
Then just run `gradle clean` or `grale build` or simply `gradle createPom`.

This will generate it as pom.xml in the root of the project. Although you can replace `writeTo("pom.xml")` with `writeTo("<anyDir>/newpom.xml")`.

The resulting pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sg.test.spring.web.guide</groupId>
    <artifactId>sg-web-initial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add some lines to build.gradle to generate maven plugin entries in the pom file?

Comment: The code here will eagerly create the pom.xml file even if you don't need it. (Should probably have it inside a doLast block)

Comment: @Trejkaz Isn't this only if we call the createPom task? In that case, doesn't that mean we need it? When would doLast make a difference?

Comment: @Drew the current code is writing the file at configuration-time because the call to writeTo is directly inside the task configuration block. Merely configuring the task should be causing the file to get written. (And in this case the configuration is being done eagerly, because tasks.register isn't being used either. If changed to tasks.register, it will likely only configure the task if it's about to actually get run, although even that depends on what else is in the build script.)

Comment: No dependencies written in the pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward a few years and a few major Gradle releases, in Gradle 7.5.1 this is how one would approach this with the [built-in publishing plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/publishing_maven.html) ([latest docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)). This has the benefit over hand-writing the pom like above that it automatically gets a lot of the properties, dependencies from the normal Gradle setup:

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
}
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
tasks.named("generatePomFileForMavenPublication").configure {
    def publication = publishing.publications.maven
    destination = rootProject.file("${publication.artifactId}-${publication.version}.pom")
}
```

alternatively without mutating the built-in task we can copy it wherever needed:

```
tasks.register("copyPomToRoot") {
    def publication = publishing.publications.maven
    def generatePom = tasks.named("generatePomFileFor${publication.name.capitalize()}Publication")
    dependsOn(generatePom)
    def output = rootProject.file("${publication.artifactId}-${publication.version}.pom")
    outputs.file(output)
    doLast { output.bytes = generatePom.get().destination.bytes }
}
```

---

As a side-note: if you need a pom.xml, you probably don't just want it in your repo root, but want to publish to a proper maven repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70758552/253468.