# Gradle createPom doesn't seem to read gradle.properties

Tags: groovy, gradle

**Please note:** Although I mention the [ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin in this question, it is just for providing full context. I am confident any Gradle Guru can answer this, regardless of their knowledge level of ShadowJar.

Currently my Groovy project is built with the following Gradle build invocation:

> gradle clean build shadowJar

Running this invocation produces a packaged fat jar under `build/libs` with the `version` property specified in my `gradle.properties` file. For instance, if `gradle.properties` has a `version=1.2.3`, then the above invocation produces `build/libs/myapp-1.2.3.jar`.

What it *doesn't* produce, however, is a valid POM for my app. And so I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283856/4009451) and modified it a bit to produce:

```
task createPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId ${group}
            artifactId 'myapp'
            version ${version}
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}
```

My *thinking* is that `group` and `version` (both specified in `gradle.properties`) would be "injected", and that this should produce a `pom.xml` in the same directory as my fat jar.

After adding the `createPom` task, I run:

> gradle clean build shadowJar createPom

And I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\workspace\blah\myapp\build.gradle' line: 89

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':createPom'.
> No signature of method: java.lang.Object.$() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Collections$EmptyMap, null) values: [[:], null]
Possible solutions: any(), is(java.lang.Object), wait(), find(), dump(), grep()

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.673 secs
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```groovy
groupId ${group}
artifactId 'myapp'
version ${version}
```

Are not valid groovy, and should probably be:

```groovy
groupId "${group}"
artifactId 'myapp'
version "${version}"
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `groupId "${group}"`, vs. `groupId group`

Comment: Nothing... Indeed, yours is probably better