# How can I add a properties section to a gradle generated pom file?

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin

So I know how to generate a pom file using the maven plugin in gradle, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281927/how-to-make-gradle-generate-a-valid-pom-xml-file-at-the-root-of-a-project-for-ma).

Now I want to include a properties section to the generated pom, for example like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycorp.mycomponent</groupId>
  <artifactId>mything/artifactId>
  <version>myversion</version>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
  <properties>
    <bom_status>SUCCESS</bom_status>
    <bom_url>http://jenkins/job/build-mything/9735/</bom_url>
    <bom_md5sum>ac69702b40cd3f68cd76a1a2d59ae08d</bom_md5sum>
    <bom_sha1sum>b4cf32524b42a7bf0b8cdba8a383624525bd7727</bom_sha1sum>
  </properties>
</project>
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as you generated the POM itself.

Once you generated the pom object, you can do:

```
def updatePomWithProperties(pomObject) {
    pomObject.project {
        properties {
            bom_status = "SUCCESS"
            bom_url = "http://jenkins/job/build-mything/9735/"
            bom_md5sum = "ac69702b40cd3f68cd76a1a2d59ae08d"
            bom_sha1sum = "b4cf32524b42a7bf0b8cdba8a383624525bd7727"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange... I got to `properties {...}`, but then I never know when to put in an assignment vs a function call. Also, it's interesting that I have to first generate the object, then apply the change. I tried doing it in one swoop, and that gets me a bizarre "location" error.