# convert gradle to maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a sample application with a build.gradle as below. I'm trying to convert it to maven

I'm new to gradle and maven, but have slightly more knowledge of maven, so want to stick with it for now.

I read some instructions as https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa

I put the "apply plugin maven" line in to get a pom file generated as per the instructions. When I run gradlew install I get the following error

```
Execution failed for task ':install'.
```

> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
>   Cannot publish artifact 'hello-world-java.jar' (C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld-Java\build\libs\hello-world-java-0.1.0.jar) as it does not exist.

I've previously been working fine with this project (running it from InteliJ IDEA). 
I've also previously successfully converted another project (console based) to maven.

I've also seen https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html#sec:configuring_publishing_tasks
However I don't actually want to publish the archive, i just want the equiveelent pom.xml. I notice that the install task doesn't exist if i dont have the maven plugin. I also tried just doing gradlew compile, but it didn't generate the pom.xml. I guess i need to read more about the mavin plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar{
    mainClassName = 'com.intuit.developer.helloworld.Application'
}



jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'hello-world-java'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-data:4.0.1")
    compile (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '4.0.1', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')   
    compile (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'oauth2-platform-api', version: '4.0.1', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')   
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
    compile("org.json:json")
    compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.17")
    compile (group: 'ant', name: 'ant', version: '1.7.0')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the generated `pom.xml` also?

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281927/how-to-make-gradle-generate-a-valid-pom-xml-file-at-the-root-of-a-project-for-ma

Comment: The gradle version `2.3` is really old- I'd update that to the latest one.

Comment: can you clarify- do you need a `pom.xml` file because you need to re-build this same project using Maven?

Comment: I want to have pom.xml in order to manage the dependencies in a fashion I'm familiar with. I have other (closely related) projects already in maven

Comment: I'll try upgrading gradle...

Answer (score 1):

The Maven POM generated by a Gradle build *only* contains the information needed for consumers of the project: dependencies.
The POM will have no configuration about building the library itself using Maven, like plugins and other things.

Comment: and is there any workaround for that? to create the pom file with plugins and other things.