# Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build an android app on my Windows machine. getting below error while building.
I have been working on my android project since 2 months but now i am getting error
i am using android studio 4.2.1 while i tring to build apk it gives error i don't know how to use
mavenCentral()   please help

```
            Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
```

i  recenty added   mavenCentral() in build.gradle

```
               allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
//    jcenter() //  Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon ( 
     // i replaced jcenter() to   mavenCentral()
   }
      }
```

[image: screen shot of error]

[image: build.gradle]

other Gradle file code is this

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
      apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

      android {

          compileSdkVersion 30
          buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myshop"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

  buildFeatures {
      viewBinding true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility kotlin_version
    targetCompatibility kotlin_version
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
  }

 dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
// glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
//Adding coroutines to a project
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I found a solution for this [in a pom file](https://qascript.com/mvn-compile-error-compilation-error-error-source-option-5-is-no-longer-supported-use-7-or-later/). Unfortunately that means you have to make a pom file.

To generate the pom file you'll need to follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283856/3252344).

After you have the pom.xml file generated, try adding this:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```