# Could not find method pom() of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask after gradle upgrade to 7

Tags: gradle, upgrade, maven-plugin, maven-publish

I'm upgrading gradle from 2.6 to 7.0 and after the upgrade I'm getting this error

Could not find method pom() for arguments ... on task  of type org.grale.api.DefaultTask.

after I removed the apply plugin: 'maven' which was deprecated and replaced in with 'maven-publish'

I tried to find the replacement for pom method in mavel-publish, but I did not succeed

```
task createPomFiles {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId groupId
            artifactId 'generic-connector'
            version version
        }
    }.writeTo("$project.buildDir/resources/../pom.xml")
}
```

Relates to: [How to make gradle generate a valid pom.xml file at the root of a project for maven users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281927/how-to-make-gradle-generate-a-valid-pom-xml-file-at-the-root-of-a-project-for-ma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a `pom.xml` file for your Gradle 7.0+ project, I suggest you the following steps:

#### 1. Add maven-publish to Plugins Declaration

I reckon you already did that, but for reference:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

#### 2. Define a Publication

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            groupId = 'com.github.tcsizmadia'
            artifactId = 'gradle-sandbox'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

            pom {
                name = 'Gradle Sandbox'
                description = 'Sandbox Project for Gradle Builds'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to customise the definition for your needs (`groupId`, `artifactId`, etc.). For reference, see [Maven Publish Plugin's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven)

#### 3. Create a Task to Rename pom.xml (Optional)

As a *nice to have* feature, you can add a task to rename and copy the generated `pom.xml` file.

```
tasks.register('renamePom') {
    doLast {
        def pomFile = file("${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml")
        if (pomFile.exists()) {
            def newPomFile = file("${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}/resources/main/META-INF/maven/pom.xml")
            newPomFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()
            pomFile.renameTo(newPomFile)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I specified a task to copy the default `build//publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml` to `build/pom.xml`. Feel free to modify as you need.

#### 4. Finalise the Build with pom.xml Generation

It's not mandatory, but if you wish to have your `pom.xml` generated with your builds, append this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication.finalizedBy(renamePom)
build.finalizedBy generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
```

If you skip this step, you can generate your pom.xml for your project issuing:

```
./gradlew generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
```

#### A Minimalistic Full Example

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.github.tcsizmadia'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            groupId = 'com.github.tcsizmadia'
            artifactId = 'gradle-sandbox'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

            pom {
                name = 'Gradle Sandbox'
                description = 'Sandbox Project for Gradle Builds'
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('renamePom') {
    doLast {
        def pomFile = file("${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml")
        if (pomFile.exists()) {
            def newPomFile = file("${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}/resources/main/META-INF/maven/pom.xml")
            newPomFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()
            pomFile.renameTo(newPomFile)
        }
    }
}

generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication.finalizedBy(renamePom)
build.finalizedBy generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I'm new to gradle. Do you have any idea why this rename does not work though?  def pomFile = file("$project.buildDir/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml")
        if (pomFile.exists()) {
            pomFile.renameTo("$project.buildDir/resources/main/META-INF/maven/pom.xml")
        }

Comment: I'm glad if it works for you! Re. `$project.buildDir` - it's deprecated, _I think_ you need to use `${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that also, it does not create /resources/main/META-INF/maven/pom.xml file

Comment: @IoanaTeodoraJipa gotcha! My bad. Modified my answer and now the `renamePom` task creates the destination directories. Please try again! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I tried your new approach, I did not work at first because it seems that gradle does want to create folders named "main", that was the reason why I couldn't find the pom.xml, I only created the first folder named "resources" once I removed the "main" folder from the path "${layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile}/resources/META-INF/maven/pom.xml" the pom.xml file was renamed successfully and all intermediate folders were created. Thank you for your responses. I appreciate it.